# How much memory does a C# reference consume?

Tags: c#, .net, reference

How much memory does a C# reference consume?
Does References consumes memory as much as the object itself?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A reference is implemented as a pointer, so in an application that runs in x86 mode (32 bit), a reference is four bytes, and in x64 mode (64 bit), a reference is eight bytes.

As the reference is just a pointer to an object, the reference is the same size regardless of what it is pointing to, or even if it doesn't point to anything at all (null).

Comment: I was going to answer this but I stopped when I started to wonder that there surely must be some additional overhead memory involved in the creation and maintenance of a reference beyond the pointer itself.

Comment: @Ashigore: There is actually no overhead at all in a reference, it's just a pointer. Any overhead is associated with the object, like type information and garbage collection references.

Comment: Downvoter: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 15):

A reference consumes the native word size of the platform it is running on.

That is, 32-bit: 32 bits. 64-bit: 64 bits.

So no.. your object can be variable in size.. the reference will always be as above.

Answer (score 7):

From [C# 5.0 in a Nutshell: The Definitive Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449320104) in page 22;

> *Reference types require separate allocations of memory for the
>   reference and object. The object consumes as many bytes as its fields,
>   plus additional administrative overhead. The precise overhead is
>   intrinsically private to the implementation of the .NET runtime, but
>   at minimum the overhead is eight bytes, used to store a key to the
>   object’s type, as well as temporary information such as its lock state
>   for multithreading and a flag to indicate whether it has been fixed
>   from movement by the garbage collector. **Each reference to an object
>   requires an extra four or eight bytes, depending on whether the .NET
>   runtime is running on a 32- or 64-bit platform.***