# IQueryable async extension methods exact time execution and returned task

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, task, iqueryable

I have a method that returns data from the database

```
public Task<List<T>> GetAsync(int someId)
    {
        return dbSet
            .Where(x => x.Id == someId)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

I have a dictionary that stores Task by some key

```
Dictionary<int, Task<List<T>>> SomeDictionary { get; set; }
```

In some other place I get the Task and put it in the dictionary

```
var someTask = repo.GetAsync(someId);
someInstance.AddInDictionary(key, someTask);
```

Then I get the task and await it to get the result

```
var task = someInstance.GetFromDictionary(key);
List<T> result = await task;
```

So my questions are:
1. Where do the IQueryable translate to sql query and execute in the database:
   when I call the method in the repo

```
var someTask = repo.GetAsync(someId);
```

-or when I await the task

```
List<T> result = await task;
```

2. In the dictionary, when I store Tasks

```
Dictionary<int, Task<List<T>>> SomeDictionary { get; set; }
```

...do I store only a operation that should return a result, or a operation together with the actual result? In other words, does saving the Task instead of saving the List, save any memory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is in `ToListAsync()`, same as with `ToList()`

Comment: For what purpose would you like to know when this is executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `await` keyword is effectively syntactic sugar. It works in a *similar* (not same) fashion to a callback, where the callback is the code proceeding the `await`. It does not control when or how the `Task` is executed.

This means that Entity Framework is responsible for scheduling and executing the `Task` without knowledge of `await`, and therefore has the ability to schedule the `Task`'s execution however it desires.

Depending on how `ToListAsync` is implemented, it may contain a portion of code which executes immediately and synchronously with the current thread.

I have not seen Microsoft state *when* the `IQueryable` is translated in to SQL, or the connection to the SQL server is initiated. My guess would be that the `IQueryable` is translated to SQL and the connection handshake starts immediately upon calling `ToListAsync`, and that the remainder of the method is executed as soon as possible on one of the `ThreadPool` threads.

That being said, calling code should be written in such a way that it does not rely on the internal operations of the asynchronous method.

As for the second part of your question, `Task` is a reference type. It has the same [memory overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606439/how-much-memory-does-a-c-sharp-reference-consume) as any other reference type. If you declare `N` fields to house `N` `Tasks`, you'll end up with `N * B bits`, where B is `32` or `64` depending on your operating system. If you store them in a `List`, which is also a reference type, you'll probably end up consuming more memory, because `List` internally keeps a larger array than is necessary so it can append/prepend items more efficiently. If you store `N` `Tasks` in an `Array` of `N` elements, you'll end up with `(N + 1) * B` (could be more, not sure), since the array is also a reference.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I wanted to know because it is related to my second question (and also with a dose of curiousity).

Comment: Edited for the second part of your question. :D

Comment: I have just seen the edit...so an IEnumerable stores the pointers to the objects rather than the objects?

Comment: `IEnumerable` is an interface. It does not store anything (though the CLR does keep it's Type definition in memory). `List<T>` and `Array<T>` both implement `IEnumerable`, but `IEnumerable` has nothing to do with the *storage* of the items but rather how those items can be accessed.

Comment: You are right, I meant IEnumerable implementations.

Comment: Value types are stored in the places they are declared. A `byte` field will reserve a byte of memory for every instance of the class/struct on which the field exists. An `object` field is going to reserve 32 or 64 bits of memory for every instance of the class/struct on which that field exists. The memory reserved for the *instance* of the object is elsewhere on the heap, and the `object` field simply points to it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c